# Derive (id, siblings-ids) table from (id, parent-id) table

Tags: c#, mysql, ontology

*Summary*: I have a table of concepts `concept(id, definition, parent-id, path-to-root)`, and I want to create an extended-table of concepts `extended_concept(concept-id, definition, parent-id, siblings-ids)`, where `siblings-ids` is a comma-separated string like `'sibling-id-1,sibling-id-2,..'` with a minimum number of siblings equals to 3.

---

*Details*: I have the following:

1. A table of concepts `concepts(id, definition, parent-id, path-to-root)` that represents an ontology (graph).. it contains 10,000,000 records.

Here are some sample records:

```
('A28681773', "definition2", 'A32452653', 'A24672666.A24681708.A24674976.A27414154.A32452653')
('A33193765', "definition1", 'A24670862', 'A24672666.A24681708.A24674976.A27414154.A27414079.A24679016.A24670862')
```

2. A C# program that aims at creating a large `.csv` file which contains `(concept-id, definition, parent-id, siblings-ids)` excluding concepts that have less than 3 siblings

I think that relying on C# to build this `.csv` file has high complexity in terms of time and space.. I could not come up with a sql query to build such a table, which -by the way- will be easy to just export the table as `.csv` file.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"where siblings-ids is a comma-separated string like 'sibling-id-1,sibling-id-2,..' with a minimum number of siblings equals to 3."_ - **what?!** No. You should normalize your database design.

Comment: Hi @Dai, I mentioned that all I want from the database is deriving a `.csv` file.. I have nothing to do with the database after getting this `.csv` file.. and yes, the extended table will be deleted after getting the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..

1. Group the concepts by parent-id and use `group_concat` aggregation function to put all kids in a comma-separated string beside its parent.

```sql
create view parent as
(
# group_concat is the aggregation function that will concat the fields of Id Column in a comma-separated string
select Parent_Id as Id, group_concat(Id) as kids, count(Id) as kids_count
from concept
group by Parent_Id
having kids_count > 3); # must be > 3, not >= 3, because later we will exclude the concept from being a sibling for itself..
```

2. Join `parent` and `concept` tables where concept.Parent_Id = parent.Id. Some string manipulation is needed (via `replace` and `trim` functions) to fix errors that happened when we exclude the concept from being a sibling to itself.

```sql
create table extended_concept as
(
select 
       concept.Id,
       concept.Parent_Id,
       concept.Definition,
       # excluding the concept from being a sibling to itself will produce errors like: it will convert 'Id1,Id2,Id3' to ',Id2,Id3' or 'Id1,,Id3' or 'Id1,Id2,'
       # so to fix it we will trim BOTH leading and trailing',', and replace ',,' with only one ','
       TRIM(BOTH ',' from
            REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(parent.kids,
                            concept.Id,
                            ''),
                    ',,', ',')
           )
                                   as siblings,
       (parent.kids_count - 1) as siblings_count # because we excluded the concept from being a sibling for itself
from concept
         inner join
     parent
where concept.Parent_Id = parent.Id
order by siblings_count ASC
); -- count = 9,759
```

3. This `extended_concept` is exported as a `.csv` file and then dropped along with the parent view

```sql
drop view parent;
drop table extended_concept;
```